# How to switch radeon to amdgpu

Tags: drivers, radeon, amdgpu

I'm trying to play Fallout 4, but this game using Intel video card. I can run everything i want with DRI_PRIME=1, and it will use AMD. But not Fallout -_-

So I think, that the problem with AMD driver (because it is the first recommendation in every second web-site, to upgrade the video-driver)

My system:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Intel core i7 6820HQ
- AMD Radeon HD 8750M
- 16GB RAM

So...
I have 2 drivers installed (I think).
Here is the output of `sudo lspci -v (The part with AMD)`

> 01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] (rev 81)
> Subsystem: Dell Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M]
> Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 132
> Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
> Memory at ef200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
> I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
> Expansion ROM at ef240000 [disabled] [size=128K]
> Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 
> Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
> Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
> Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
> Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 
> Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
> Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
> Kernel driver in use: radeon
> Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu

Here is the output of `inxi -Ga`

> Graphics:
> Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel
> bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:191b
> Device-2: AMD Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] vendor: Dell
> driver: radeon v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 1002:6600
> Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: none compositor: gnome-shell
> v: 3.36.4 tty: N/A
> OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
> v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.0-devel (git-0399959 2021-01-06 focal-oibaf-ppa)
> direct render: Yes

Kernel driver in use: radeon. So how to switch it to amdgpu?
And why the second command shows `driver: none`

Ask me, if you need the output of some command.

P.S. I saw the very similar questions, but it didn't help...
(https://ask-ubuntu.ru/questions/491091/ya-dumayu-chto-ya-ispolzuyu-radeon-vmesto-amdgpu-kak-ya-mogu-izmenit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update grub according to your video card.

### First step:

**There are two options:**

- First is Sea Islands (Southern Islands) (Radeon HD 7000 and 8000 series)
- And the second is Caribbean Islands (Radeon Rx 300 series and 7000 A-series APUs)

For more details visit
Sea Islands (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon#Southern_Islands)
Caribbean Islands (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon#Caribbean_Islands)

### Second step:

You should open terminal and type the following command:
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Then edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` according to the first step.

For Sea Islands the value for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` should be

```
radeon.si_support=0 
amdgpu.si_support=1
```

And for Caribbean Islands it should be

```
radeon.cik_support=0 
amdgpu.cik_support=1
```

So the final string should look like:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1"`

When you finish editing press ctrl+O to save and ctrl+X to close.

### Third step

Use the command `update-grub` or `update-grub2` and then reboot using the `reboot` command.

THAT'S ALL.

It didn't work for me because I had unwanted arguments (don't remember which ones, but it started like amd.*)

Wish you luck!