# Many games on Steam and Lutris are not detecting my laptop's dGPU and running on iGPU

Tags: wine, games, steam, radeon, lutris

Many wine games that I run through Steam(like Hitman 2 and Shadow of the Tomb Raider) and Lutris(all Epic Store and GOG games) are not detecting my AMD Hainan dGPU(even with `DRI_PRIME=1`) and are running on iGPU, resulting in a poorer performance. I have checked GPU usage in all these games through `radeontop`. Native Linux games(like Life is Strange) and few wine games are detecting my dGPU and using it. How to make other wine games run on my dGPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced another issue along with this and found a solution, which works for both of the problems. I am attaching the link to the solution:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1359975/1170351